# JS fetch print details of bad request response

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, response, fetch-api

I am trying to use Django-rest-auth, I am getting it to work but often I get Bad request HTTP 400. In Django-rest-auth generated view I can see the details of the error (i.e username contains unaccepted chars or pwd do not match).

How can I get this information on frontend js side ? For now I was trying to just console the whole response but cannot find it in there

```
    const registerUser = async (user ) => {
      console.log( JSON.stringify(user))
      const response = await fetch("/api/dj-rest-auth/registration/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
      });

      if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log('did it ! !!! !! !!! ! !! ')
        let data = response.json()
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('authToken', data.key);

      } else {
        console.log(response);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the network tab in dev tools?

Comment: Also, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) is how you catch an error in js

Comment: Yes, those response bad request details are in the network tab, I can see them. But I am interested in programmatic way to access them

Comment: `try..catch` or `catch` on the promise

Comment: Oh, hmm okay makes sens. I can make verifications (pwd1/pwd2 match, username format etc.) before fetch then, thank you

Comment: That comment, was to someone suggesting I should not put those details to the front end, what was my end goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try...catch` as stated in comments by [Konrad Linkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad-linkowski).

```js
const registerUser = async (user ) => {
      console.log( JSON.stringify(user))
   try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/dj-rest-auth/registration/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
      });

      if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log('did it ! !!! !! !!! ! !! ')
        let data = response.json()
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem('authToken', data.key);

      } else {
        console.log(response);
      }
}catch (e){
console.log(e) // log the error , its an object so you can get desired error message
}
    };
```

Comment: thank you, is it a standard practice to wrap fetch into try/catch ?

Comment: yes, it is. Even `axios` has to be dealt with same way

Comment: try/catch is the only way I've been able to get this to work. .then()/.catch() does not work completely.  I can catch the error, but cannot pull out the custom message.

Comment: @AlfredBr you can get the custom message by logging the error and check for error message in the json `catch(e){console.log(e}`